# Vuejs multiple forms different values same method

Tags: forms, vue.js, checkbox, nuxt.js

I have a page with three same forms but with differents dynamic values each. What i want to achive is to take the inputs of the specifiec form when checkbox checked. My work so far is:

```html
<form ref="form">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input ref="submit" type="checkbox" value="1" name="question" @click="choiceCheck">
    <input type="text" :value="dynamic feedback 1" name="feedback">
    <input type="number" :value="dynamic points 1" name="points">
    <h2>Dynamic value 1</h2>
  </label>
</form>
<form ref="form">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input ref="submit" type="checkbox" value="2" name="question" @click="choiceCheck">
    <input type="text" :value="dynamic feedback 2" name="feedback">
    <input type="number" :value="dynamic points 2" name="points">
    <h2>Dynamic value 2</h2>
  </label>
</form>
<form ref="form">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input ref="submit" type="checkbox" value="2" name="question" @click="choiceCheck">
    <input type="text" :value="dynamic feedback 3" name="feedback">
    <input type="number" :value="dynamic points 3" name="points">
    <h2>Dynamic value 3</h2>
  </label>
</form>
```

And my script

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [],
      feedback: "",
      points: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    choiceCheck () {
      this.$refs.submit.click()
      console.log(
       this.$refs.form.feedback.value + this.$refs.form.points.value)
    },
  },
};
```

With this method take always the last form fields, i want when check the checkbox to take form data belong to this checkbox!

Comment: You can create an object of all of your dynamic values, then you can pass the key of the dynamic value and the actual value to `choiceCheck`. Once this method is called, you can get the key of your object and mutate it to the new value.

Comment: Can you share a visual example plz?

Comment: You're asking me to write the whole code for you here, SO is not a free coding service. Let's do the opposite: you make an effort of trying something hard enough, then we could maybe help you debug it.

Comment: No my friend i need to learn, i just ask for reference at least to study and make posible to achieve what i need! Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a place to learn (this is written in the guidelines). There is actually a closing reason for this (asking for tutorials). If you want to study something, go take a course, read a book or read some documentation. Here, you can search for a question, ask for a question and have some help to debug some code. You will not get mentored from A to Z for free by somebody. If you want that, you can look for a mentor. Otherwise, my previous comment was already giving you some guidelines on how to achieve this. The next step is to write the actual code and maybe debug it.